# Different meanings of the word "typical"

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

As an adjective, perhaps because of encompassing several meanings, the word **typical** is one of those complicated words to me. I have always confronted with various applications of the word in many occasions and got used to utilize it or interpret it based on its situation in any sentence. But I have decided to make some examples here for its different meanings (at least based on my understanding) in order to define whether I have been correct in my interpretations so fat or not. So I wonder if you let me know how would you rephrase each one of these sentences or what does it means in each sentence below:

**Example #1:**

> - A typical working day, begins at 8 a.m. [To me the word "typical" in this sentence stands for **"ordinary"**]

**Example #2:**

> - His behavior is fairly typical of his generation. [to me it means: **"His behavior is quite ordinary (nothing seems to be strange) in his behavior"**] Moreover, I really don't know much about the meaning and the use of the structure **typical of**.

**Example #3:**

> - It is typical of men not to notice women changes in appearance often. (I would rephrase it as follows: "**It is ordinary that men do not often notice changes of women in appearance.** E.g. when they dye their eyebrows.) Also, I really don't know much about the meaning and the use of the structure **typical of**.

**Example #4:**

> - Tokyo is a typical example of a crowded place. [The word "typical" in this sentence means **"good**" to me.]

**Example #5:**

> - This meal is typical of local cookery. [Here, the word "typical" means **"sample/example"** to me. So I would interpret the whole sentence as follows: **"This food is a sample / example of local cookery."**

**Note:** although all dictionaries have had an attempt to provide many examples, but regarding this specific word, I think all of them have acted weakly and no explanation is clear-cut. So I wonder if you give me a hand to interpret it in an understandable way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The word "typical" is derived from "type" (of course), and the dictionaries I checked mention "type" somewhere in their definitions of "typical".

Your proposed meaning of "ordinary" is fine, but it should be understood as "ordinary *considering what category the thing is in* (what its *type* is)."

So, when the doctor says a chest X-ray is "typical for a tuberculosis patient," he is not saying it is "ordinary". He means it is **like most** (tubercular) X-rays.

And if you are talking about an **example** of something, like in your #4 sentence, if the example is **like most**, then it's a "good" one. But that doesn't mean "typical" means "good".

The same goes for your sentence #5: That meal is **like most** (in the local cookery category).

The dictionaries I have looked at seem to get the idea of "typical" across pretty well (given that they write in dictionary-ese, and try to be concise, general, and accurate all a the same time.) For example, [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/typical)'s definition seems reasonable to me: "combining or exhibiting the essential characteristics of a group".

If you keep in mind that "typical" is derived from "type" and involves characteristics of a group, then "typical" isn't really such a complicated idea.